# Can't Connect to Website on Certain ISPs (Too Many Redirects)

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, redirect

I'm having a strange problem all of a sudden, and I'm pretty sure I've eliminated the application as the culprit, but I'm not a server admin by nature so I could be wrong.

- https://launchwestco.com
- Linode
- Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
- Nginx 1.10.1
- Laravel 5.2

From my home, office and other networks it loads fine. On Verizon, it is not loading, giving an error of too many redirects. This is true when loading on my phone or on my laptop tethered to my phone.

The problem seems to have cropped up last night, or at least that's when we noticed it.

I suspect it's something in the server config, but my Nginx config seems correct:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 ipv6only=off;

    server_name launchwestco.com *.launchwestco.com;
    rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=off;

    server_name launchwestco.com *.launchwestco.com;
    root /home/forge/envoyer/com.launchwestco/current/public;
    client_max_body_size 55M;
    underscores_in_headers on;

    # FORGE SSL (DO NOT REMOVE!)
    ssl_certificate [...]/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key [...]/server.key;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location ~* /auth/(.+) {
        return 301 /authentication/$1;
    }

    # FORGE CONFIG (DOT NOT REMOVE!)
    include forge-conf/launchwestco.com/server/*;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/launchwestco.com-error.log error;

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}

upstream discourse { server 127.0.0.1:85; }
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name community.launchwestco.com;
    return 301 http://community.launchwestco.com$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name community.launchwestco.com;

    # FORGE CONFIG (DOT NOT REMOVE!)
    include forge-conf/launchwestco.com/server/*;

  location / {
    access_log off;
    proxy_pass http://discourse;
  }
}
```

`netstat -tlp` shows the following (truncated to only http/s output):

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 *:http                  *:*                     LISTEN      4880/nginx -g daemo
tcp        0      0 *:https                 *:*                     LISTEN      4880/nginx -g daemo
tcp6       0      0 [::]:https              [::]:*                  LISTEN      4880/nginx -g daemo
```

(I'm not sure why a line for `[::]:http` is missing ... and I don't know if it matters for this particular issue.)

Even if I insert code like `die('DEBUGGING');` as the first line in the front controller of the app—the first executed line of PHP that should be run—the error still occurs, and I don't get the output expected from the app.

I'm having the hardest time troubleshooting it. There are definitely redirects built into the app, but those don't seem to be the culprit because they're behaving as expected on most ISPs. It's only on Verizon Mobile that the issue occurs (that we're aware of anyway).

Any ideas what could be causing our problems?

Comment: It redirected for me as well, and on Comcast. I'm looking into it... But it would be helpful if you would post the actual `server` blocks, rather than the example ones you've given, in addition to any other `server` blocks that might be active on the server.

Comment: http://ipv6-test.com/validate.php says that it is ipv6 ready, but something may be confusing there for Comcast and Verizon. Try to eliminate the ipv6 configuration.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I updated the post with the entire config for that site. There are several sites on the server, too many to post here, but they're all boilerplate. Hopefully this helps some.

Comment: @JonahB I ran the same test and got the same results. I tried with and without the config, but maybe I need to give it longer. (Actually, after removing the config and DNS entry, I'm seeing improved results. May be the answer, time will tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are having is that your web site works when accessed via IPv4, but returns too many redirects when accessed via IPv6.

To resolve it:

Your nginx configuration has errors that *should* cause it to fail to load.

In particular, you've specified `ipv6only=off` in your IPv6 `listen` directives, but also specified IPv4 `listen` directives along with them. The expected response to this is nginx returning an error `98 Address already in use` and exiting (or refusing to reload the config). If nginx is still running, it is likely with an old config.

You should first remove `ipv6only=off` from each `listen` directive, as it is redundant and unnecessary.

You should then add the IPv6 `listen` directives to the `server` blocks which are missing them.

Comment: Thanks, I pulled all IPv6 config and DNS entries and so far that's working. I'll give this a try in the next few days and see if I can get it working with v6 setup. Honestly, I've done a lot of research and I can't at all figure out exactly what the `ipv6only=off` really does.

Comment: @JoshHudnall It does what it says in [the documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#listen). And please don't disable IPv6. Some people won't be able to visit your web site at all, and it will be slower for many others.

Comment: @michael-hampton which people are not able to visit ipv4 sites?

Comment: @JonahB At the moment, only a very tiny number of people in various places in south and southeast Asia, where there just aren't any IPv4 addresses to be had at any price, and large scale NAT hasn't been deployed yet. But that number is likely going to grow.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, how were you able to confirm the redirect issue was present for v6 only? Is there a test suite o can use or configuration I can set to ensure I'm testing one or the other? I haven't had a lot of luck searching for ways to do that.

Comment: @JoshHudnall I have IPv6, so I tried it both ways.